# How to prevent ubuntu updates wiping my custom kernel modules?

Tags: drivers, kernel, updates, custom-distributions

I am using ubuntu server 20 LTS for an IoT application. I have a few custom kernel modules that I have installed and work fine, however whenever ubuntu does updates on boot they are wiped as if they never existed.

One option would be to disable automatic updates. However I am not sure how robust that disablement method is and whether it will be eventually be insufficient for a certain type of unknown future update.

However, in order to also benefit from the updates of a maintained OS like 20 LTS, I would like to keep automatic updates. I am thinking perhaps there is a separate module repository in usr/lib or lib/local or something that will allow me to keep getting updates while keeping my custom kernel modules.
Thank you!

Comment: If you have the source code for your modules, you can have DKMS automatically rebuild them to match the corresponding kernel update. That's the usual method for modules using Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Please be specific with details; are you asking about Ubuntu Core 20 Server? or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server?   You mention 20 which implies it's the *snap* only server product (which has a support life of 10 years), but also mention the LTS which is only used by the 20.04 *deb* based release (all *year* releases have 10 years of supported life so LTS isn't mentioned normally; only some *year.month* releases are LTS thus it's mention). 20 is a different product to 20.04; the *year* format being used to signify that since 2016.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So to be specific its Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit for raspberry pi 4.